# Azure browser push notification for chrome, firefox ,and safari browser

Tags: c#, angular, azure, push-notification, azure-web-app-service

How can i implement browser push notification using azure notification hub that can send push notification to chrome,Firefox and safari browsers.I need to implement this for a very high scale users.

Answer (score 1):

Basically without Azure Notification Hub, you can try to send push notification to different browsers using Web Push API which works on the lastest Chrome & Firefox I tried, please see the Mozilla document for [Push API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Push_API) to know it. And there is [a cookbook site for Web Push](https://serviceworke.rs/web-push.html) to show some examples to help getting started. Then, you can host your web push server on Azure.

*Note: Due to the API of Web Push which be experimental, I don't know whether it works on Safari because of no Mac I have.*

Meanwhile, considering for serving a very high scale users, to integrate Google Cloud Message with Azure Notification Hub, you can try to refer to an old Google blog [Push Notifications on the Open Web](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notifications-on-the-open-web) and the Azure tutorial of [Google](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started)/[Firebase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) Cloud Message for Android to create an instance of notification hub and configure it with GCM/FCM to send push message via Web Push to browsers.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Waiting for others to throw the light on it. Do u have any Github link where you have implemented this. It would be great and good for me to get started off.